# Завершить работу приложения

Tags: java, android

Друзья, подскажите как правильно завершить работу приложения (выйти полностью).
Сейчас использую метод завершения активностей,но он скидывает меня в главную активность, откуда у меня осуществляется логин. А как сделать так чтобы приложение полностью завершилось? Logout + terminate

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: System.exit(0) или android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid()) выбирайте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.putExtra("Exit", true);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Теперь на главной Активити в onCreate добавь

```
setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

if( getIntent().getBooleanExtra("Exit", false)){
    finish();
    return;
}
```

**Или второй вариант**

Есть метод **finishAffinity ()**, которая будет закрывать текущий Activity и все родительские Activity, но он работает только в Android 4.1 и выше